# How to find the value in JSON format

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible-facts

This command "aws iam get-account-password-policy" gives a output in the JSON Format.

```
{
    "PasswordPolicy": {
        "MinimumPasswordLength": 15,
        "RequireSymbols": false,
        "RequireNumbers": false,
        "RequireUppercaseCharacters": false,
        "RequireLowercaseCharacters": false,
        "AllowUsersToChangePassword": false,
        "ExpirePasswords": false,
        "PasswordReusePrevention": 5
    }
}
```

from this i need to extract "MinimumPasswordLength" and "PasswordReusePrevention" values such as 15 and 5 .
Can anyone suggest me how to do or have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
aws iam get-account-password-policy --query "PasswordPolicy.MinimumPasswordLength"

aws iam get-account-password-policy --query "PasswordPolicy.PasswordReusePrevention"
```

For further reference.

> Documentation link - [Controlling command output from the AWS CL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output.html)